# SVG and text-shadow, difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

When creating a 3D effect on some SVG text by stacking a bunch of text-shadows through CSS I get very different results between Chrome and Firefox. See the example below and the screenshots below that.

What causes this difference and how to avoid it? Or should I perhaps use a better method for creating this effect?

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="100px">
  <defs>
    <style>
      text {
        fill: white;
        font-family: Arial, Sans;
        text-shadow: -1px 1px #1E00BE, -2px 2px #1E00BE, -3px 3px #1E00BE, -4px 4px #1E00BE, -5px 5px #1E00BE, -6px 6px #1E00BE, -7px 7px #1E00BE, -8px 8px #1E00BE, -9px 9px #1E00BE, -10px 10px #1E00BE;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
  <text x="100px" y="50px" font-size="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: FF]

Comment: on Chrome i see the screenshot for FF your posted

Comment: Interesting, on chrome 65 for Android, I get the same result as you, but on the same chrome 65 on macOS, I get the FF result. This would tend to a platform specific bug on chrome side, so the best to do is to let them know about it by [opening a ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/), and specify your own platform.

Answer (score 2):

`text-shadow` is meant to be for HTML elements, the fact that it (mostly)  works on SVG shouldn't be relied on. It's possible that it's not displayed at all on IE, for example.

I would suggest to replicate the effect with multiple text elements, example:

```html
 <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="100px">
      <defs>
        <style>
          text {
            fill: #1E00BE;
            font-family: Arial, Sans;
            font-size: 50px;
            text-anchor: middle;
            dominant-baseline: middle;
          }
          text:last-of-type {
            fill: white;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
      <text x="100" y="50">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="1" dy="-1">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="2" dy="-2">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="3" dy="-3">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="4" dy="-4">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="5" dy="-5">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="6" dy="-6">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="7" dy="-7">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="8" dy="-8">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="9" dy="-9">Hello</text>
      <text x="100" y="50" dx="10" dy="-10">Hello</text>
    </svg>
```